# ajax- if I send an ajax request on a url, can i check in the php page if it is a request or the page has been opened?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

For security purposes, I want to stop the users from being able to view or send anything to the php pages I am going to use for ajax purposes.

So is there any way by which I can check whether a page has been called because of an ajax request or the page has been opened?
Does self=top consider ajax request or not?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: Why does it, from a security perspective, matter if the data is sent from a page or via Ajax? You should never trust data provided by a user, no matter how it is sent to you.

Comment: This question bothers me, What added security does this add?
It doesn't matter how it is sent: Royal mail or parcel force, it could still contain something nasty when it arrives. What's more someone voted this question up.

Comment: For example i have a simple ajax based chat, so I can just check it up if the chat comes from the previous page or someone has gone to the url and added some spam into someone elses account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  /* special  for ajax here */
}
else
{
  //its a page request
}
```

this will only work when using JS frameworks that send this header :-by Bergi

Comment: Please add a note that this will only work when using JS frameworks that send this header...

Comment: anyone can easily add a custom header like x_REQUESTED_WITH in header so for critical operation you can't use this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need an other security model.

Of course you could set custom http headers (like [`X-Requested-With`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requested-With)) or such when you are doing Ajax requests (many libraries do that automatically), and tell them apart from normal "view" requests. But everything can be faked, so there can be no security through determining that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do stop people not using a ajax request, what's stopping people from changing the ajax request in the first place?

This would add little to none added security in my opinion especially with the ease this can be done with firebug for example.

Comment: That is fine. I am checking the rest of the things I just want to check if the user is trying to add unrelevant stuff by directly getting to the url and making different types of GET posts